# MSBuild: CopyToOutputDirectory does not copy a native DLL to the output

Tags: .net, msbuild

I have a solution with 2 projects: `MSBuildQuestion.csproj` and `NativeLibrary.vcxproj`.

`MSBuildQuestion.csproj` produces `MSBuildQuestion.exe`. `NativeLibrary.vcxproj` produces `NativeLibrary.dll`.

`MSBuildQuestion.csproj` references `NativeLibrary.vcxproj` via a `ProjectReference` and also copies the `NativeLibrary.dll` to its output via `CopyToOutputDirectory`:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\NativeLibrary\NativeLibrary.vcxproj" />
    <Content Include="..\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\*.dll">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

When I clean (by deleting all the output folders) and then build the solution from a command line via MSBuild, it does not copy `NativeLibrary.dll` to the output of `MSBuildQuestion.csproj`, despite the `CopyToOutputDirectory` explicitly telling it to do so. This of course leads to the "Unable to load DLL 'NativeLibrary.dll'" error when I am trying to run `MSBuildQuestion.exe`.

Am I missing something and that is not how native DLLs should be referenced from `*.csproj`? Or is it rather a bug in MSBuild?

This is how I clean, build and run my solution:

```
Get-ChildItem . -include bin,obj,x64 -Recurse | ForEach-Object ($_) { Remove-Item $_.FullName -Force -Recurse }
nuget restore
msbuild /p:Platform=x64 /p:Configuration=Release
.\MSBuildQuestion\bin\x64\Release\net6.0\MSBuildQuestion.exe
```

The project that reproduces the problem is [here](https://github.com/yaskovdev/sandbox/tree/master/MSBuildQuestion).

---

One observation: if I run `msbuild /p:Platform=x64 /p:Configuration=Release` twice, the `NativeLibrary.dll` gets copied and then everything works. As if MSBuild violates the order in which the projects must be built. Although if I check the MSBuild logs, it does not seem to violate the order, because the next lines are logged in the expected order:

```
Done Building Project "...\NativeLibrary.vcxproj"
Done Building Project "...\MSBuildQuestion.csproj"
Done Building Project "...\MSBuildQuestion.sln"
```

Comment: `ProjectReference`s will be resolved to assemblies used for compilation. A project that doesn't produce a managed assembly will not resolve. Following a `clean` when the `<Content Include="..\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\*.dll">` is evaluated (in the same phase as the `ProjectReference`), there is nothing for the wildcard to match. Remove the `ProjectReference` in the .csproj and set the build order in the solution file (`MSBuildQuestion.sln`).

Comment: I removed the `ProjectReference` and specified in the solution file that `MSBuildQuestion` has `NativeLibrary` as a dependency. Now it works as expected. Thank you for the suggestion, @JonathanDodds! Consider posting your comment as an answer so that I could accept it.

Comment: However, this approach does not seem to work in case of transitive dependencies, does it? Suppose I have `MSBuildQuestion2.csproj` -> `NativeLibraryWrapper.csproj` -> `NativeLibrary.vcxproj` (first via `ProjectReference`, second via `ProjectDependencies` in solution file). In this case `NativeLibrary.dll` is not copied to the output of `NativeLibraryWrapper.csproj`. [This project](https://github.com/yaskovdev/sandbox/blob/master/MSBuildQuestion2/README.md) illustrates the problem. Do I have to add `NativeLibrary.vcxproj` to `MSBuildQuestion2.csproj`'s dependencies as well? That looks hacky.

Comment: `NativeLibrary.dll` is not a dependency for compiling because it is not a managed assembly. `NativeLibrary.dll` is a dependency for the runtime `DllImport` attribute but MSBuild doesn't know about runtime dependencies. That `NativeLibrary.dll` has been copied to the output directory of the `NativeLibraryWrapper` project doesn't make it a dependency. Changing the solution to make `NativeLibrary` a build dependency of `MSBuildQuestion2` won't fix the issue. That only effects the build order.

Comment: Changing the solution to make `NativeLibrary` a build dependency of `MSBuildQuestion2` (in the solution file) fixed the issue (just tried it [here](https://github.com/yaskovdev/sandbox/blob/master/MSBuildQuestion2)). :) As you said, it effects the build order. But the issue is caused by the wrong build order, that's why it wroks as a fix. I'm just wondering if there is a way to configure the build order in a simpler way. Adding `NativeLibrary` as a build dependency to every project that references it (directly or transitively) does not seem to be a robust solution: too easy to forget to do it.

Comment: It is not a build order issue. Did you also add `NativeLibrary` as `Content` of `MSBuildQuestion2`?

Comment: Just tried, it did not help, unfortunately. Currently, `NativeLibrary.dll` does not even get copied to the output of `NativeLibraryWrapper` if I build the _whole_ solution with `msbuild /p:Platform=x64 /p:Configuration=Release` (despite it being the build dependency of `NativeLibraryWrapper`), so adding it as `Content` to `MSBuildQuestion2` is not expected to help, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `NativeLibrary.dll` is NOT a Dependency

Managed code is code written to the .NET CLR (either the .NET or the .NET Framework implementations). A managed code project can have compilation dependencies on other managed code assemblies. But a native code assembly can't be a compile time dependency. The interoperability of managed code calling native code is at runtime.

A C# project can have a set of `ProjectReference` items. `ProjectReference`s are resolved to assemblies that are compilation dependencies. A native assembly can't be a compilation dependency. `NativeLibrary.dll` is not a dependency of your C# projects, not directly and not transitively.

`NativeLibrary.dll` is a dependency of the `DllImport` attribute in the code but that's at runtime. And the build knows nothing about runtime dependencies.

### Build Order

The build order of projects is determined from the `ProjectReference` items across projects and from the `Project Dependencies` set in the solution file.

Setting a project dependency in the solution only effects the build order. It doesn't make a reference or a 'dependency'.

### MSBuild Phases

MSBuild has two phases when handling a project: [evaluation and execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/build-process-overview?view=vs-2022). In the evaluation phase 'top level' item groups are resolved.

### MSBuildQuestion.sln Example

`MSBuildQuestion.csproj` contains:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    ...

    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\NativeLibrary\NativeLibrary.vcxproj" />
        <Content Include="..\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\*.dll">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

During the evalaution phase MSBuild will see and handle both the `ProjectReference` and the `Content`.

The `ProjectReference` to `NativeLibrary.vcxproj` influences the build order. MSBuild will know to build `NativeLibrary.vcxproj` before the execution phase of `MSBuildQuestion.csproj`. Because it's a native project there is no managed assembly to compile with.

`Content` will be evaluated and, unless there are files hanging around from a prior build, will match nothing.

During the execution phase there is a step that copies files that were added to `Content`. Unless there were files left from a prior build that satisfied the wildcard during the evaluation phase, `NativeLibrary.dll` will not be in `Content`.

(BTW Use `PreserveNewest` over `Always` if you want incremental builds.)

To make this example work:

- Remove `<ProjectReference Include="..\NativeLibrary\NativeLibrary.vcxproj" />` from the `MSBuildQuestion.csproj`.
- Modify the solutuion file so that `MSBuildQuestion.csproj` has a project dependency on `NativeLibrary.vcxproj`.

The solution will build `NativeLibrary.vcxproj` before `MSBuildQuestion.csproj` ensuring that the evaluation phase of `MSBuildQuestion.csproj` will see current built files for `NativeLibrary.vcxproj`. `NativeLibrary.dll` will be part of `Content` and will be copied as part of `Content`.

### MSBuildQuestion2.sln Example

In this example:

- `MSBuildQuestion2.csproj` builds a .exe assembly with a dependency on `NativeLibraryWrapper.dll`.
- `NativeLibraryWrapper.csproj` builds a .dll assembly with a `DllImport` of `NativeLibrary.dll`.
- `NativeLibrary.vcxproj` builds the native DLL `NativeLibrary.dll`.

When a project reference is resolved to a reference to a managed assembly, transitive managed dependencies will be copied. Files that match the name of an assembly that is being copied (e.g. .pdb files) will be copied.

`NativeLibrary.dll` is none of these.

This could be solved like the previous example:

- Modify the solution file to set a project dependency that `MSBuildQuestion2.csproj` depends on `NativeLibrary.vcxproj`.
- Add `NativeLibrary.dll` as `Content`.

Yes, this is not DRY and is easy to forget.

Another apporach would be to have `NativeLibraryWrapper.csproj` publish a folder or a package. Consumers written in managed code would use the published folder or package instead of directly referening the project.

Comment: Great explanation, thank you! It seems like Microsoft [provides a way](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/incorrect-solution-build-ordering-when-using-msbuild-exe/) to use `ProjectReference` to merely order the build (and even discourages using the solution file for that), but the approach does not work if you have a mix of managed and native projects. I think publishing `NativeLibraryWrapper` as a package is the way to go then.

Comment: Yes, mixing managed and native projects is not well supported.